# How do I change the background image on all of my screens and keep the changes

Tags: java, javafx, background-image, fxml

**Important Information and Approach**

So I have this method (that is incomplete at the moment) whose sole purpose is to change the background image in every screen. Here is the method that does this.

```
if(optionButton1.isArmed())
{
    optionButton1.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground1"));
}
else if(optionButton2.isArmed())
{
    optionButton2.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground2"));
}
else
{
    optionButton3.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground3"));
}
```

So what this code does at the moment is check to see what button has been pressed and released and changes the old id to a new id. Once it changes it to a new id, it will change the id in the FXML File and then the FXML file will go into my css file and look for the id that matches the new id.

Now this FXML variable is in one of my controller class(**OptionscreenController**) and the variable's name is Optionmenu. It look likes this in my controller class

```
@FXML private StackPane Optionmenu;
```

this mean that optionmenu is the main root of the FXML File that this method changes.

One of my challenges are to find a way to bring all the nodes or roots to this class and change the ids of those nodes as well if possible.

**Here was my attempt at solving this problem:**

```
   try
    {
        FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAIN));
        myLoader.load();
        mainMenu = myLoader.getRoot();
        mainMenu.setId("BlueBackground2")
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(OptionscreenController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

What i was thinking of doing was loading up a FXML file with another FXML file beside the main one, **use getRoot() to get the object** inside the FXML File, add it to a variable that has the same **fx:id** and use the **setId** to change its old id.

Now there are two problems with this: first and foremost, doing it this way will invoke the override method initialized to run no matter what(every controller has to have this method). So I said, ok so I won't use FXMLLoader.load(). I'll just go straight to getRoot() immediately. Turns out it sets the FXML variable to null.

The last challenge I have is keeping the changes made to each background as the user transition from screen to screen.

These are the challenges that I'm facing at the moment.

---

**Code Time**

The first thing that I think you need to see is how I transition from screen to screen. There will be alot of code to look at so please bear with me if you can.

**ScreenNavigator class-Use to load and set the screen**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class ScreenNavigator extends StackPane
{

    private HashMap<String, Node> screens = new HashMap<>();

    public ScreenNavigator()
    {
        super();
    }

    public void addScreen(String name, Node screen)
    {
        screens.put(name, screen);
    }

    public Node getScreen(String name)
    {
        return screens.get(name);
    }

    public boolean loadScreen(String name, String resource)
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader myLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(resource));
            Parent loadscreen = myLoader.load();
            ControllingScreens ScreenController = myLoader.getController();
            ScreenController.setScreenParent(this);
            addScreen(name, loadscreen);
            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean setScreen(String name)
    {
        if (screens.get(name) != null)
        {
            if (!getChildren().isEmpty())
            {

                Timeline transition = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), (ActionEvent event) ->
                {
                    getChildren().clear();
                    getChildren().add(screens.get(name));
                }));

                transition.play();
                MillionaireTriviaGame.fade(true);
            }
            else
            {
                getChildren().add(screens.get(name));
                MillionaireTriviaGame.fade(false);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("The screen wasn't able to load.");

            alert.showAndWait();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Next is the main class that use this class.

**Main Class**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MillionaireTriviaGame extends Application
{
    private static final Rectangle fillRectangle = new Rectangle();
    public static final String MAINSCREENID = "main";
    public static final String MAIN = "MenulayoutFXML.fxml";
    public static final String OPTIONSCREENID = "option";
    public static final String OPTION = "Optionscreen.fxml";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage menuStage) throws Exception
    {
        ScreenNavigator controller = new ScreenNavigator();
        controller.loadScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID, MillionaireTriviaGame.MAIN);
        controller.setScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(controller, fillRectangle);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1366, 768);
        fillRectangle.setWidth(scene.getWidth());
        fillRectangle.setHeight(scene.getHeight());
        fillRectangle.setDisable(true);
        menuStage.setScene(scene);

        menuStage.setOnCloseRequest(e ->
        {
            Alert exitConfirmation = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Are you sure you want to exit this application?");
            exitConfirmation.setTitle("Exit Application");
            exitConfirmation.setHeaderText("Confirm Exit");
            Optional<ButtonType> choice = exitConfirmation.showAndWait();
            if (choice.get() == ButtonType.OK)
            {
                menuStage.close();
            }
            else
            {
                e.consume();
            }
        });

        menuStage.setTitle("Let's play who wants to be a millionaire");
        menuStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/ImageFiles/gameIcon.png").toExternalForm()));
        menuStage.setFullScreen(true);
        menuStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void fade(boolean inOut)
    {
        FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(5), fillRectangle);
        ft.setFromValue(1);
        ft.setToValue(0);
        if (inOut)
        {
            ft.setDuration(Duration.seconds(0.5));
            ft.setFromValue(0);
            ft.setToValue(1);
            ft.setAutoReverse(true);
            ft.setCycleCount(2);
        }
        ft.play();
    }
}
```

Next is the controller class that is responsible in changing the background image for all screens.

**OptionscreenController**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;

public class OptionscreenController implements Initializable, ControllingScreens
{
    private ScreenNavigator controller;
    private MediaPlayer optionMenuPlayer;
    @FXML private Button backToMain;
    private BooleanProperty isDisabled;
    @FXML private StackPane Optionmenu;
    @FXML private Button optionButton1;
    @FXML private Button optionButton2;
    @FXML private Button optionButton3;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        configureProperties();
        playSong();
    }

    private void configureProperties()
    {
        isDisabled = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        backToMain.disableProperty().bind(isDisabled);
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreenParent(ScreenNavigator parentScreen)
    {
        controller = parentScreen;
    }

    private void playSong()
    {
        Media optionIntroTheme = new Media(getClass().getResource("/millionairetriviagame/AudioFiles/OptionMenuMusic.mp3").toExternalForm());
        optionMenuPlayer = new MediaPlayer(optionIntroTheme);
        optionMenuPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        optionMenuPlayer.setVolume(0.1);
        optionMenuPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
    }

    @FXML private void changeBackgroundScreen() // This is the method where it all happens.
    {
        if(optionButton1.isArmed())
        {
            optionButton1.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground1"));
        }
        else if(optionButton2.isArmed())
        {
            optionButton2.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground2"));
        }
        else
        {
            optionButton3.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground3"));
        }
    }

    @FXML private void goToTheMainMenu()
    {
        isDisabled.setValue(true);
        optionMenuPlayer.stop();
        controller.loadScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID, MillionaireTriviaGame.MAIN);
        controller.setScreen(MillionaireTriviaGame.MAINSCREENID);
    }
}
```

**And the interface that controls which screen to show(each controller has this method).**

```
package millionairetriviagame;

public interface ControllingScreens 
{
     public void setScreenParent(ScreenNavigator parentScreen);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Here is one solution I came up with:

In my screenNavigator class, I added this method:

```
private String getBackgroundId()
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String backgroundId = "";

    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Background.txt"));
        backgroundId = br.readLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return backgroundId;
}
```

Then in the same class, I added two lines of code to the loadScreen method

```
 mainMenu = myLoader.getRoot();
 mainMenu.setId(getBackgroundId());
```

Here is the method that overrwrites the file.

```
private void changeBackgroundId(String backgroundId)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try
    {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Background.txt", false));
        bw.write(backgroundId);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if (bw != null)
            {
                bw.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is how the changeBackgroundScreen looks now

```
@FXML private void changeBackgroundScreen()
{
    if(optionButton1.isArmed())
    {
        optionButton1.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground1"));
        changeBackgroundId("BlueBackground1");
    }
    else if(optionButton2.isArmed())
    {
        optionButton2.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground2"));
        changeBackgroundId("BlueBackground2");
    }
    else
    {
        optionButton3.setOnMouseClicked(e-> Optionmenu.setId("BlueBackground3"));
        changeBackgroundId("BlueBackground3");
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

The way this solution works is that each time I transition from screen to screen, I will load the only line in the backgroundId file and that is the id inside the css file. Once the user clicks on the button to change the background(look at the optionScreenController class), I will write to the file and override the old Id with the new Id so that every screen will load the new background. It's a decent solution to both of my problems. If anyone else thinks they can improve this solution, please do.